# JSON return to python iterable

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get this return:

[Google API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Broadway%20Manhattan&sensor=false)

Into a Python iterable object

So far I have this:

```
request = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/%s?address=%s&sensor=%s" % (self._output, self._address, self._sensor)
data = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
decoded_data = json.loads('[%s]' % data).pop()
    if decoded_data.get("status") == "OK":
        return decoded_data
    return ""
```

However this only turns the outer "wrapper" into a dictionary. I want to decode the entire block so I can access the values easily and raise exceptions where needed.

Comment: It's rather unclear to me what you are trying to do.  Why doesn't `json.loads(data)` do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you wrapping it in a list? It's a JSON object, which maps very cleanly to a Python dictionary. Just do `decoded_data = json.loads(data)`, then you can do `decoded_data['results'][0]['formatted_address']` etc.

Comment: nevermind the list, I am trying to find a clean method to get to the deeper values avoiding too much nesting